# How to transfer values from one column to another column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the DataFrame when I am doing Python using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
items = ['Apple','Cherry','Banana','Apple','Banana']
place = ['UK','','China','USA','China']
quality = ['Bad','Bad','Good','Bad','Good']
date = ['Jan-1','Jan-2','Jan-3','','Jan-1']

df = pd.DataFrame({"Item":items, "Place":place, "Quality":quality, "Date":date})
print(df)
```

| Item | Place | Quality | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | UK | Bad | Jan-1 |
| Cherry |  | Bad | Jan-2 |
| Banana | China | Good | Jan-3 |
| Apple | USA | Bad |  |
| Banana | Chian | Good | Jan-1 |

What I require is:

- If column `Place`is null and column `Date` is not null, then transfer the value from `Date` to `Place`;
- If column `Place`is not null and column `Date` is null, then no transferring happens;
- If column `Place`is and column `Date` is are both null or not null, then no transferring happens, either.

So I tried:

```py
df.Place=np.where(df.Date!="",df.Date,df.Place)
```

but this can not be satisfied with what I require. The output should be like this:

| Item | Place | Quality | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | UK | Bad | Jan-1 |
| Cherry | Jan-2 | Bad | Jan-2 |
| Banana | China | Good | Jan-3 |
| Apple | USA | Bad |  |
| Banana | Chian | Good | Jan-1 |

Can someone help me with this solution? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions of `np.where` seems to be incomplete:

```
df = df.replace('',np.nan)
df['Place'] = np.where(df['Place'].isna() & df['Date'].notna(), df['Date'], df['Place'])
```

or without replacing `''` with `NaN`, just write the complete condition:

```
df.Place = np.where((df.Date!="") & (df.Place==""), df.Date, df.Place)
```

As @mozway explains, note that `df.Date!=""` is redundant because if it's False, then we select from `df.Place` (regardless if it's `""` or not) and if it's True, it depends on if `df.Place==""`. So what really decides the selection is `df.Place==""`. Then we can write the above simply:

```
df.Place = np.where(df.Place=="", df.Date, df.Place)
```

Output:

```
     Item  Place Quality   Date
0   Apple     UK     Bad  Jan-1
1  Cherry  Jan-2     Bad  Jan-2
2  Banana  China    Good  Jan-3
3   Apple    USA     Bad    NaN
4  Banana  China    Good  Jan-1
```

Comment: Note that the condition to check if the Date value is empty is useless. You shouldn't care about it, an empty string is an empty string, this won't change the output. This just adds an unnecessary test ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the empty strings with NaN and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with your other column:

```
df['Place'] = df['Place'].replace('', float('nan')).fillna(df['Date'])
```

The correct code with `numpy.where` would have been:

```
df['Place'] = np.where(df.Place!='', df.Place, df.Date)
```

output:

```
     Item  Place Quality   Date
0   Apple     UK     Bad  Jan-1
1  Cherry  Jan-2     Bad  Jan-2
2  Banana  China    Good  Jan-3
3   Apple    USA     Bad       
4  Banana  China    Good  Jan-1
```